# smtplib: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, ssl, smtplib

I'm try to send an email in python usign the library smtplib. But I have this error:

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'smtp.mydomain.es'. (_ssl.c:1129)

```
import smtplib, ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mydomain.es', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls(context=context)
server.ehlo()
server.login('email@mydomain.es', 'mypassword')
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: If I use context = ssl._create_unverified_context() instead of create_default_context() it works good!! But I'm afraid if using _create_unverified_context may be dangerous.

Comment: If you are using the mail server of your hosting provider: You likely use the wrong domain name to access the mail server, please study the providers documentation on how to do it correctly. If you are maintaining the server yourself:  you have the wrong certificate installed.

Comment: Hi. There is no error in domain name because it works well with ssl._create_unverified_context(). The problem is the certificate (create_default_context()), but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: *"because it works well with ssl._create_unverified_context()"* - the point of this function is to create a context without verification and hence no hostname verification. Of course it works then even if the wrong hostname is used.